# Multinomial choice with binary observations

Tags: maximum-likelihood, discrete-data, paired-data, bradley-terry-model

Is there a standard name for a multinomial choice model where the observations are in the form of binary questions such as "do you prefer A to B" and "do you prefer B to D"?  This seems like a common occurrence, and the likelihood is easy enough to write out by hand, but I'm having trouble searching for references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood the question, this refers to paired preference (1) or [pair comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_comparison) data. A well-known example of such a model is the Bradley-Terry model (2), which shares some connections with item scaling in psychometrics (3). There is an R package, [BradleyTerry2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BradleyTerry2/index.html), described in the JSS (2005) 12(1), [Bradley-Terry Models in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v12/i01/paper),  and a detailed overview in Agresti's CDA, pp. 436-439, with R code available in Laura Thompson's textbook, [R (and S-PLUS) Manual to Accompany Agresti’s Categorical Data Analysis (2002) 2nd edition](https://web.archive.org/web/20110805121758/https://home.comcast.net/%7Elthompson221/Splusdiscrete2.pdf).

**References**

1. Thurstone, L.L. (1927). A law of comparative judgment. *Psychological Review*, *3*, 273-286.
2. Bradley, R.A. and Terry, M.E. (1952). Rank analysis of incomplete block designs I: The methods of paired comparisons. *Biometrika*, *39*, 324-345.
3. Andrich, D. (1978). Relationships between the Thurstone and Rasch approaches to item scaling. *Applied Psychological Measurement*, *2(3)*, 451-462.