# Next Best Product Modeling (Seeking reference material)

Tags: self-study, modeling

I am being tasked with developing a "next best product model", and at this time, I can safely say that I do not know where to start!

In other words, I want to develop a model that will provide guidance into what product we should try to get a customer to use/purchase next. For example, if a banking customer who is 47 years old, that currently has a checking account and debit card (10 years of tenure with the bank), and has a FICO score of 650, what product should we try to cross-sell them with next?

I am not seeking any specific answers as this is a broad question, but I would like to pick your brains for helpful reference textbooks and/or articles related to these types of models.

Comment: Looks like a ranking problem. Maybe worth to look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30976/how-to-get-started-with-rating-and-ranking-based-on-pairwise-competition-data).

Comment: Question: Is that post would be more appropriate on datascience.stackexchange.com, as the object is more business than academia?

Answer (score 3):

If you considered this a ranking problem, look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30976/how-to-get-started-with-rating-and-ranking-based-on-pairwise-competition-data).

If you want to look at the cutting edge methodologies used in the business, you could dig in the forum of [the home-depot competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/home-depot-product-search-relevance).
The subject is the same: finding the best next product, but the competition is not yet finished.

For nearly similar subject, you could also look at the github page of the [crowd flower winner](https://github.com/ChenglongChen/Kaggle_CrowdFlower).
In that case, the most efficient method is a particularly well chosen set of features combined with an ensemble selection.

In the Allstate competition, the second is a [random forest](https://github.com/alzmcr/allstate) well calibrated.

Generally, random forest and gradient boost are considered reliable model.
If you want to try more "fancy" algorithm, you could try [bayesian model](http://mc-stan.org/) or [neural network](https://mxnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). But I considered the first not handy with big dataset (> 100K individuals, >60 features) and the second painful to parameterise, and advise so to use mainly for unsupervised task.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you essentially want to "predict" what product the customer would most interested in purchasing next?

Approaches with classifiers such as Naive Bayes and Logistic Regression may be a good place to start. These can output the probability of an event occurring given previous historical data. For example you could have product A, and run a classifier that will output the probability that a customer will buy product A, based on their previous purchases.

Here is a sample chapter on classification from an "Introduction to Data Mining". It helped me understand some of the basic concepts of classification and prediction http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch4.pdf

Witten & Frank's (2005) "Data Mining: Practical machine learning tools and techniques" is also a very good book that I've gotten a lot of good information from.

I'm currently doing research into this area for my masters, so if this seems like it's of relevance to you, I can give you some more of the literature I've found so far

Answer (score 1):

It should be really easy to do:

But the gist is this: you create a "document" for each product. Add different fields to the document such as price, category. total historical sales and product description.
Use similarity metric as a basis for a recommendation. For example, this is a cosine between feature vectors. You then offer the top N products based on some additional criteria (e.g. not in the user's viewing history, in stock, etc).

An up-sale list would require the same category but a higher price.
A cross-sale list would require the same category but a lower price and high sales.

You can improve this model by boosting the importance of different features (price * 10, + word matched/10) or by adding more data.

E.g. also indexing all historical shopping carts and matching in the same way with the current shopping cart.

You can have a look at [Lucene in Action, Second Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/lucene-in-action-second-edition) "Lucene in action" for all the details.

Also, if you don't want to write your own search engine, you can use Google Analytic's Enhanced E-commerce to collect data and use its related product feature to get [recommendations](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6223409?hl=en) via api