# Bradley-Terry models by using R?

Tags: r, self-study, bradley-terry-model

I want your help to Apply the Bradley-Terry models on any particular sport or any other idea of an application by using R. I am not familiar with R, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Your preceding question was closed because it was hard to tell what was asked. The present question add no more context. You should consider providing more information: what is the research question, what hypothesis you want to test, what data are available. Examples on the use of BT models are available on this site, if you are only interested in seeing R applications: [How to fit Bradley–Terry–Luce model in R, without complicated formula?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26994/930). Without more information from your part, this question will be closed as well.

Comment: Statisticians are familiar with the Bradley-Terry model. I discussed it before with regard to a specific ranking question.  Herbert A. David wrote a book on paired comparisons many years ago (1963) that included the Bradley-Terry Model.  Here is an amazon link to that monograph.  http://www.amazon.com/The-method-paired-comparisons-David/dp/B0000CLWGP/ref=1a_B001HD3N4Y_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1342732412&r=1-2

Answer (score 4):

First you'll want to learn some R.  There are lots of tutorials linked [here](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html).

When you have at least a beginner's grasp of R you'll want to install and use the [BradleyTerry2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BradleyTerry2/) package.  The following [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v48/i09/paper) by its authors should show you how to do that.

Comment: Thank you Conjugate Prior. I will do what you seid. Thanks again.

Comment: I can apply Bradley-Terry models in SAS because I am familiar with SAS But I feel that SAS not very useful in Bradley-Terry models. My Superviser ask me to use R. My information about it is not enough. I do not do more constricts in R when I apply in my data example .